# AS3 How to find a control point of a Bezier Curve based off where a user draws a line with their mouse

Tags: actionscript-3, bezier

Im Trying to create a Bezier curve with the start point where the mouse is first clicked, and the end point where it is released. The control point should be the furthest point away from the start and end point, is there a way to do this without storing all mouse positions in an Array.

I have tried just finding the rightmost or leftmost point but have realised this wouldn't work when it is drawn from left to right (seeing the furthest away point would be up or down) I could try and implement both these together however im not to sure this would work well, since the end point would then generally be the furthest away point

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us what have you coded until now and exactly where your problem is.

Comment: @Gio I actually think this question is answerable as-is.  Agreed in general that sample code is always nice, but the concept seemed clear enough to take a crack at answering.

Comment: Only in general terms, which is not what SO is about. They're using AS-3, which is not a stand-alone language, it's principally used in Adobe projects, so without seeing any code, and no mention of what has already been tried, there is no way for people to _properly_ comment on how to do what this person wants to do, in the environment they're working in. Sure, we could explain how to construct a Bezier [from first principles](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo) but that doesn't mean it'll be a good answer.

Comment: @Davo176, what kind of Bezier (quadratic, cubic)? In which environment (e.g. which APIs do you already have available)? What have you already tried (e.g. can you show the code you already have that you're not stuck on)? Also, if the requirement is "the control point is the furthest away from start/end": why do you need a Bezier curve at all? If you just want a connector, why not go with the much simpler to create circular arc instead? Can you show a picture of what you're trying to achieve? Because you might not need to store anything beyond start/end but that's almost impossible to say now.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for your help, Im still new to coding but have worked out a solution which I am happy with, for those wondering, I am just working out the furthest left, right up and down points then calculating the distance between the start and the end points, and using the one with the greatest value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With this approach, you'll definitely need to store the mouse positions in an array.

Imagine clicking on the middle-right of the screen, then moving the mouse to roughly draw two W's backwards, then releasing the mouse on the middle-left of the screen.

Clearly the control point should be on one of the bottom points of the W's, but which one?  You have to measure the distance between your start and end points to each candidate in order to figure out where the true furthest-away point is.

*Advice*:  It might help to have a mechanism to explicitly declare the control point.  Maybe click once to set the control point, then click and drag to define the endpoints of the curve?  Or keep track of clicks on your canvas:  First is the start point, second is the control point, third is the end point.  Depending on the constraints of your project, there could be a lot of options.

Comment: Cheers Brian. I considered doing this but I think it feels more intuitive to just draw a curve for my project. I have since worked it out to a point I am happy with. Thank you.